# How can we create a loop so that user can input a name until it matches any one name included in text file using c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I want user to input a name that we already had listed in text file. Until a user give a name that matches with a name which contain in our 'itemlist.txt' file user have to input another name and when a name matches the loop should be break. I was trying to do like this....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int production, price;
string category, item, itemname;

int main(){

    ifstream findItem("itemlist.txt");
    while(true){
        cout << "item: ";
        cin >> itemname;
        while(findItem >> category >> item >> production >> price){

            if(itemname==item){
                break;
            }
        }

        if(itemname==item){
            break;
        }
        cout << "Item couldn't be found in our data base." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the actual question about your program?

Comment: Please don't be unresponsive, edit your question so we can understand your problem.

Comment: Actual problem is my code is not working just as i want. And the question is how to make it works, user give a name if its in itemlist.txt file loop break and if it does not find then loop start again to give a chance to a user to input new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it now, you only get one pass through the file. If the first item entered is not in the file, you reach the end and cannot read any more. A very minor tweak will make your program work (albeit, very inefficiently). Just put the `ifstream` creation inside the loop.

```
while(true){
   ifstream findItem("itemlist.txt");
   ...
```

That way, you are opening and reading through the file each time through the loop.

Don't do that. It is extremely inefficient. A much better solution is to read the contents of the file (or at least, the parts that are necessary) into a data structure which can be searched efficiently, such as a hash set (e.g. `std::unordered_set` from the standard library `<unordered_set>` header).

```
std::ifstream findItem("itemlist.txt");
std::unordered_set<std::string> items;
while(findItem >> category >> item >> production >> price)
    items.insert(item);
```

Then you can search for your item from this set.

```
while(true){
    std::cout << "item: ";
    std::cin >> itemname;
    if (items.count(itemname))
        break;
    std::cout << "Item couldn't be found in our data base." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ya you understand me very well and i tried your 1st suggestion and it works. as you can guess i am new to c++, i want you to explain me little more about your 2nd suggestion if possible. i am confused about unordered_set<std::string> items;

Comment: @Nawa: Read about it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set -- If, after reading that documentation, you still have specific questions about it, ask them in a new post. Or you can ask here if it is specifically related to my answer.

Comment: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: @Nawa: Yes, `std::unordered_set` is a C++11 feature. So you need to enable C++11 in order to use it. The error message explains that. If you can't use C++11, there are C++98 hash sets available in third party libraries. For example, in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/unordered.html). Or you can simply replace `std::unordered_set` with `std::set` (from the `<set>` standard header). It's a tree based set instead of a hash map based set. It may give you slightly less performance, but you probably won't even notice the difference.

Comment: ok from setting i enable c++11 and it works fine. learned something new =D.

Answer (score 0):

Every time someone enters an invalid item, you go through the entire file. Then, when another item gets entered, the file pointers points the the end. You need to rewind the stream by putting this at the beginning of the `while (true)` loop:

```
findItem.gseek(0);
```

Personally, however, I would write the code to load the items into memory once:

```
struct Item {
    Item(string s) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << s;
        ss >> category >> item >> production >> price;
    }
    bool operator==(string s) {
        return item == s;
    }
    string category, item;
    int production,  price;
};

int main() {
    ifstream file("itemlist.txt");
    vector<Item> items;
    string cur;
    while (getline(file, cur))
        items.emplace_back(cur);
    string item;
    while (true) {
        cout << "item: ";
        cin >> item;
        std::vector<Item>::iterator it = find(items.begin(), items.end(), item);
        if (it ==  items.end())
            cout << "item not found";
        else break;
    }
}
```